# Issues with System.Speech.Recognition - SpeechRecognitionEngine Doesn't Pick Up Speech

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, speech-recognition, system.speech.recognition

I am having major issues trying to implement a sample provided by Microsoft on how to use the SpeechRecognitionEngine (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.speechdetected(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is the sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace SampleRecognition
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    // Initialize an in-process speech recognition engine.
    {
        using (SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer =
           new SpeechRecognitionEngine())
        {

            // Create a grammar.
            Choices cities = new Choices(new string[] { 
            "Los Angeles", "New York", "Chicago", "San Francisco", "Miami", "Dallas" });

            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
            gb.Append("I would like to fly from");
            gb.Append(cities);
            gb.Append("to");
            gb.Append(cities);

            // Create a Grammar object and load it to the recognizer.
            Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
            g.Name = ("City Chooser");
            recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(g);

            // Attach event handlers.
            recognizer.LoadGrammarCompleted +=
              new EventHandler<LoadGrammarCompletedEventArgs>(recognizer_LoadGrammarCompleted);
            recognizer.SpeechDetected +=
              new EventHandler<SpeechDetectedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechDetected);
            recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
              new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

            // Set the input to the recognizer.
            recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

            // Start recognition.
            recognizer.RecognizeAsync();

            // Keep the console window open.
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    // Handle the SpeechDetected event.
    static void recognizer_SpeechDetected(object sender, SpeechDetectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Speech detected at AudioPosition = {0}", e.AudioPosition);
    }

    // Handle the LoadGrammarCompleted event.
    static void recognizer_LoadGrammarCompleted(object sender, LoadGrammarCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Grammar loaded: " + e.Grammar.Name);
    }

    // Handle the SpeechRecognized event.
    static void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Speech recognized: " + e.Result.Text);
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like nothing works, I've tried many different examples and spent all day trying to get this to work.  If I swap out **RecognizeAsync()** with **EmulateRecognizeAsync("I would like to fly from Chicago to Miami")**, for example, it works as expected.  But it appears the program isn't getting any input from my mic.

Here are some more details:

- Windows 8.1
- .NET 4.0
- Lenovo ThinkPad built in microphone
- Visual Studios 2012
- Worth mentioning that the output from the program has this info message that is written out when the grammar is loaded:

  ```
  ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe Information: 0 : SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection.
  ```

Am I missing something? Do i need a better microphone?  Do I need to setup up the hardware in anyway besides making the mic my default mic? Do i need to use a different library for Windows 8? I'm out of ideas.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out - The mic built into the laptop cannot be used for Windows Speech Recognition at all...

I just received a new headset today and everything works flawlessly. I still recieve the information message

```
ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe Information: 0 : SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection.
```

...but everything seems be working.